# Show compilation warnings in Intellij working with Oracle and PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, intellij-idea

This code generates a `Warning: Trigger created with compilation errors.` (if for example the column doesn't exist) in iSQL*Plus, but not when executed in the console in Intellij.

```
CREATE TRIGGER triggerName
INSTEAD OF INSERT ON Table
REFERENCING NEW AS variabel

  BEGIN
    SELECT
      COUNT(*)
    INTO variabel
    FROM Table
    WHERE Table.column = 1;
  END;
```

After I have executed the above I can do `SHOW ERRORS` in iSQL*Plus and get something like `PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "TABLE"."COLUMN": invalid identifier`. Trying to do `SHOW ERRORS` in Intellij leaves me with the SHOW keyword underlined in red which prevents me from executing it.

Is there anyway to have this iSQL*Plus functionality in Intellij?

Comment: will [ALL_ERRORS](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_1052.htm#i1577005) table help you?

Comment: I did select * from all_errors and indeed it showed the errors I was looking for! However, do you know why show errors doesn't work? Is it an iSQL*Plus only feature?

Comment: Yes, but there are plugins available to support for _intellij_ like one [here](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/1800?pr=phpStorm). Indeed `SHOW ERRORS` in `iSQL*Plus` would query the `all_errors` table implicitly. The plugin should do the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [ALL_ERRORS/USER_ERRORS](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_1052.htm#i1577005) table should help you see the errors, wherever you go!

```
SELECT * FROM ALL_ERRORS WHERE NAME = 'TRIGGERNAME'
```

`SHOW ERRORS` is an `iSQL*Plus` only feature. It would *implicitly* query the above table and print the results for us.

I see some plugins available for *intellij* support. Like one [here](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/1800?pr=phpStorm). They would be using similar approach of `SHOW ERRORS`.